# odoo 10 don`t show "payments terms"

Tags: odoo, bitnami

everybody... i have this problem: when i access to my "accounting" panel i don´t find the "payments terms" button; i remember that i was able to modify the payment terms (for example: "18 days" after facturation)

i want to modify my payment terms.

i am working on bitnami's odoo solution supported by google cloud plattform, in the image below, i mark the place where i hope find the "terms payment" option  [image: odoo don`t show payment terms button]

¿so... how can i modify my terms payments?

Comment: Do you have payment and payment_transfer module installed?

Comment: i can't find the module in the app searcher...  :-(

Comment: how can i install it in the stack ?

Comment: May be you don't have acces rights to see the menu check them

Comment: i don`t know... it seems a cache problem. i've restored the old setup (from advicer to accountant ... and back again from accountant to advicer ) and is working!... the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

i've changed the admin setup ;  changing accountant to advicer. this has worked for me after several times trying to change the configuration.